# Javascript closures in firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug, closures

so...I'm trying to learn this new thing called closures... new for me....
Out of Academic interest:

DESCRIPTION

When I create global variable or function in JS - I can easily see them in firebug's DOM tab (they attached to Window object).
When I create objects - the same story. I can see objects in Firebug DOM's tab.

QUESTION:

How about variables and functions inside of closures  - where are they attached to?
I don't see these closure private variables in Firebug's DOM tab. Is that the way it's supposed to work?

```
(function () {
    var test1 = 'test'; //do't se it in DOM
    function test2(){  //do't see it in DOM
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM tab only shows the variables and functions defined globally. It never shows any local variables or functions.

Closures mean that a local variable used by a local function will remain in memory for as long as the function itself remains in memory, instead of being destroyed right away. Since it's all about being *local*, they don't show up in the list of *global* variables in the DOM tab.

Consider the following:

```
  var increment = (function(){
    var i = 0;
    return function() { 
      return i++;
    }
  })();

  increment(); // should return 0
  increment(); // should return 1
```

You can still see the value of `i`, but it's only available from within the closure, so you need to place a breakpoint on the `return i++;` line and look for `i` in the 'local variables' section of the *Script* tab.

Comment: or you can add "console.log(i)" before return statement. This way it logs the output instead of halting the code.

Comment: Closures are not listed under local variables, it's a separate context, newer versions of firefox do show the closure object separately, at least for self calling functions.

Comment: @JuanMendes Can you specify which version of Firefox you are using or Version that supports global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's old story.
Newer versions of Firebug (from 1.11.2) can show closure variables too.
Using command line enter the following.

```
closure.%variable
```

Or you can use the DOM watch panels to show the closure variables by clicking the arrow right next inside DOM tab and checking the show closure option.

More details [here](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Closure_Inspector)